# Is it possible to type directory names into Dolphin's 'Open File' dialog? Or is there an alternative file manager that can?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, filemanager, dolphin

Specifically my desire is to be able to type a path into the top of the window like you can with a normal Dolphin window - like you'd be able to using Explorer on Windows.

Or is there some alternative file manager that can do this?

**Open File dialog:**

[image]

**Normal Dolphin window (allows typing path):**

[image]

Comment: I don't use Dolphin, but doesn't the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+L work in Dolphin?

Comment: Oh my god `Ctrl+L` does work, but it defaults to an empty box rather than the current path. @Nmath I get what you're saying, but I don't understand because the dialog picker looks the same in every app I've tried. Is there any app you know that does things "right" so I can see how that looks?

Comment: I'm on 22.04 with KDE 5.25.5. I found a solution that works in every app I've tested, but I'm still disappointed compared to the capabilities of Windows Explorer - even though I'm using it in a pretty weird way.

Comment: Turns out my "solution" always opens to `~Documents`, so pretty worthless. If anyone has other ideas, I'm eager to try them.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to remedy this by following these instructions: https://nallerooth.com/posts/configure-linux-to-use-kde-file-selector/

Specifically:

> Adding the line GTK_USE_PORTAL=1 to ~/.pam_environment will tell GTK to always behave as if it were in an sandboxed environment.

Unfortunately the KDE file dialog is not as much better as I'd hoped as it still lacks much of the functionality of the full file explorer, eg cut, copy, paste - which might not be a big deal to most but would be a big help for me.

**It also always opens to `~Documents` which makes it virtually useless.**

**If you have a better answer, please share!**